# Sufficient Selenium tests?

Tags: selenium

I would like to hear opinions of what is sufficient verifying in Selenium tests. The basic idea in tests is usually go from page to page and click links, but what is the best way to know for sure that you get the pages like intended? Is it checking current url or title? Seems quite sure, but it leaves open the possibility that link is broken and gives error page. Need to go deeper? Is it common practice to locate some element on current page?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, as many as you think would suffice to ascertain the quality of the product that you are testing keeping in mind that automated test run doesn't surpass manual testing time :) and doesn't give you false positives.
It would depend a lot on your situation or the functionality you are testing.

If your application has been around long and has been tested all along, then I would have my automated tests just ensure that the flow isn't breaking in which case a couple of verifications in the end suffice.  I usually put in a bit of content checks rather than just checking the page title or the url.  If there is a common pattern that is followed across your pages to report errors, then you can look for the absence of that on the page as well.

If you know specific places where your application usually fails, coz that makes it important to regress it more or to add more verifications to ascertain quality.

Comment: Agreed that you should check as many elements as you think necessary to ensure the page is what you expect. However, this needs to be offset against making sure your tests are as flexible as possible. Brittle tests can build up a lot of technical debt over time.